# Small marginal likelihood in Gaussian Process Regression

Tags: regression, likelihood, gaussian-process

After implementing a Gaussian process regression model I am getting a negative log marginal likelihood figure that is very high (~100). What does this mean?

Comment: Why do you think it's very high? What's the benchmark?

Comment: Mine is normally over e+02 or e+03. It depends on the complexity of your dataset and noise level. Also if your dataset has a small size then it may also lead to low evidence , I.e high nlml.

Answer (score 1):

There is typically no Benchmark since the likelihood is data driven and depends on your initial values. 
1) Are you sure you are maximizing the negative log likelihood since if not you will definitely get very large positive numbers

2) What kernel are you using, if you are using the Gaussian kernel $\sigma*exp(a*|d|)$ then make sure your sigma is not close to zero as an initial start

3) You might also add a nugget effect $\sigma^{2}$ to your covariance matrix if your matrix is ill conditioned

Based on my experience the negative log likelihood should not be very large (+-10^3) if your noise is less than your signal amplitude